# Order Columns in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried what others have suggested ([Order bars in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474318/order-bars-in-ggplot) and [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)) for ordering columns and I still can't get it.

I have a dataset with a column called "Zap", which has values that I want sorted from the highest occurring count to the least. 
Here is my R code:

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(Zap) %>% 
  summarize(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Zap, y=count, fct_infreq(Zap))) +
  xlab("EA5 Zigbee Enabled")+
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(100 * percent, 1), "%")), vjust = -0.25)
```

That code didn't actually reorder anything. This is what I'm getting (not sorted)

[image]

I also tried this:

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(Zap) %>% 
  summarize(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Zap, y=count)) +

  x=reorder(Zap,Zap, function(x)-count(x)) +

  xlab("EA5 Zigbee Enabled")+
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(100 * percent, 1), "%")), vjust = -0.25)
```

But this code gives me an error:

> Error in reorder(Zap, Zap, function(x) -count(x)) :    object 'Zap'
>   not found

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: put the `reorder` line within the `mutate` statement, not in `ggplot` sequence

Comment: Thats helpful, but I'm still struggling (I'm very new to R). Here is what I tried: mutate(percent = count/sum(count), x=reorder(Zap,Zap, function(x)-count(x))) %>% But I'm getting "Error in UseMethod("summarise_") : 
  no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "factor""

Comment: try `mutate(percent = count/sum(count), Zap = reoder(Zap, count, FUN=identity))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using, thanks to @HubertL for the comment:

```r
mydata %>% 
  group_by(Zap) %>% 
  summarize(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count), Zap = reorder(Zap, -count, FUN=identity)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Zap, y=count)) +
  xlab("EA5 Zigbee Enabled")+
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(100 * percent, 1), "%")), vjust = -0.25)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can sort your x variable by their count using `reorder(Zap, -count)` as the definition of x variables of the `aes`:

```r
mydata %>% 
  group_by(Zap) %>% 
  summarize(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(Zap, -count), y=count, fct_infreq(Zap))) +
  xlab("EA5 Zigbee Enabled")+
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(100 * percent, 1), "%")), vjust = -0.25)
```

[image]

**Data example**

```r
mydata <- data.frame(Zap = c(rep("enabled",85*5),rep("enabled22",1*5),rep("disabled",14*5)))
```

Comment: is there a way to sort by two variables in using `reorder`. for example `aes(x=reorder(Zap,-count,otherVar)…`    this work for me

Answer (score 1):

The `fct_infreq()` function from the `forcats` package reorders factors by frequency and can be used instead of `reorder()`. In addition, `ggplot2` computes statistics on its own which can be accessed by the `stat()` function.

So, there is no need to aggregate the data beforehand. Instead, the plot can be created directly from the `mydata` dataset:

```
mydata <- data.frame(Zap = rep(c("enabled","enabled.22", "disabled"), 5 * c(85, 1, 14)))

library(ggplot2)

mydata %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = forcats::fct_infreq(Zap)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  geom_text(aes(y = stat(count), label = sprintf("%.1f%%", 100 * stat(count / sum(count)))), 
            stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
  xlab("EA5 Zigbee Enabled")
```

[image]

`geom_text()` requires to specify the `y` and `label` aesthetics which can be derived from the computed statistics using `stat()`.